# Make e-Mail optional on Woocommerce sign up

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, forms, user-registration

My site uses mobile login ability and that is our primary means of communication and the brick and mortar utilised this so we need to make it optional for users to enter email as we have a local sms system anyway for passwords as each customer has to validate their details first in store with in. Majority of users will use mobile not email. Tried a bunch of codes but still nothing including making it not required , need it not required on billing, registering (right now login with phone works). For billing I've tried

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'wooc_email', 15 );
function wooc_email() {
    if( $key == 'billing_email'  ){
                $registration_fields['billing_email']['custom_attributes'] = array('required'=>'false');
            }
}
```

For registration tried a few but nothing came of it and thus no code.

I know the registration process is same as WP.

Any and all help useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in functions.php. Since it is a requirement in billing, we need to set it as false.

```
// For billing email - Make them not required
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'filter_billing_fields', 20, 1 );
function filter_billing_fields( $billing_fields ) {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( ! is_checkout() ) return $billing_fields;

    $billing_fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;
    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Comment: Error: Please provide a valid email address.
Still can't register on the site with just password and phone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I would need the registration process to make email optional along with the in my account form to have email as optional. Utilising the phone number as means of contact only.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'ts_unrequire_wc_field');
function ts_unrequire_wc_field( $fields ) {
    // To mark as not required
    $fields['billing_email']['required'] = false;
    // Can be used as well
    unset($fields['billing_email']);
}
```